# How to create associations between associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm creating a translation quiz web. I have theese classes:
  - Version - a versin of the quizz. A Version has many Translations. It belongs to the teacher.
  - Test - the quiz itself. It belongs to the student
  - Translation - it contains a pair of word, one in languaje 1 and other in languaje 2
  and 2 relationships
  - TranslationsVersion - contains the list of translations for one version of the quiz
  - TranslationsVersionsTest - contains the student answers for one quiz (so, the answers for one TranslationsVersion). The student will be asked several times for each translation in one quiz, so I need it to be a N-M relationship

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :dictionary
    has_and_belongs_to_many :translations
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :version 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :translations_versions
end

class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :aception_own, :class_name => "Aception"
    belongs_to :aception_for, :class_name => "Aception"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :versions
end

class TranslationsVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :version
    belongs_to :translation
    has_and_belongs_to_many :test
end

class TranslationsVersionsTest < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :translations_versions
    belongs_to :test
end
```

My problem is that when I create a TranslationsVersionsTest:

```
tvt = TranslationsVersionsTest.create(translations_versions: tv, test: @test, round: turn)
```

I get this error:

```
NameError in TranslationsVersionsTestsController#launch
uninitialized constant TranslationsVersionsTest::TranslationsVersions
```

I think that there is a problem with the relationships becouse one of the model in this association is other association itself. Are my model well typed?

Answer (score 1):

`belongs_to` expects the relationship name in singular:

```
belongs_to :translations_version
```

Comment: I´ve changed the model as you say and then I´ve got this other error: "can't write unknown attribute `translations_version_id'". The table's name is translations_versions because it is a relationship, not for a plural.

Comment: @user1999804 make sure your `TranslationsVersionsTest`'s table contains a column named `translations_version_id`

Comment: No, it has not, because I created this table as a relation between Translation and Version, so it generate the name ended with 's'. I did it this way "rails g scaffold translations_versions version:references translation:references" and "rails g scaffold translations_versions_tests translations_versions:references test:references answer:string round:integer"

Comment: Oops, I´ve just seen that I wrote the name of the table "translations_versions" , so it was not automatically generated (as I thougth) . Is this the problem?. Don't I have to name this way this kind of relation tables?

Comment: @Julitillo, tables which make relationship between two other tables should be named with both name in plural, eg `translations_versions`. But, the class name and references to the model should be mixed with first name in plural and second in singular, eg `translations_versions` and `TranslationsVersion` , to match `ActiveRecord` naming standards

Comment: @Rodrigo, you are rigth. That´s what I had, but what about if you use this model in a new other relationship between TranslationsVersion and Test?.  The class would be TranslationsVersionsTest and then when you create a new object it search for `TranslationsVersionsTest::TranslationsVersions` but what you have is `TranslationsVersion`, and that is the problem. I think I have got myself  into a mess :) Sorry